# "I don't know how to work people."

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-meaning

I am looking for a precise meaning of this expression "to work people".

I feel like it is similar to "to be friendly to people", "to handle people with tact", "to be good at conversing with people", but I need a confirmation from an expert/native speaker.

Thank you.

**A quote from the movie "The Big Short":**

> -- Are you being sarcastic with us, Mike?
>
> -- Lawrence, I don't know how to be sarcastic. I don't know how to be funny. I don't know how to work people. I just know how to read numbers.

Comment: Well, in some cases you pull their strings.

Comment: Like in "to manipulate"?

Comment: Yes, its all those things you mentioned, done with an eye towards manipulating them.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence where you've seen this? (link and quote)

Comment: I've added an example to my question.

Comment: Thanks for the example. 'to work people' is not a set phrase, and the meaning is somewhat vague. It means something like 'do things successfully with people'. The closest thing is like "I don't know how to work venetian blinds.". You don't literally operate with people like a machine, but there is a sense of 'working with' or 'working alongside' or get things done with' people.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Your contribution helps a lot to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the transitive verb ***WORK*** depends on the context.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/work):

> ***WORK***
>   transitive verb
>
> 4a: to cause to toil or labor
>   *// **worked** their horses nearly to death*
>
> 4b: to make use of: EXPLOIT
>
> 5b: to greet and talk with in a friendly way in order to ingratiate oneself or achieve a purpose
>   *//politicians **working** the crowd*